# ESP8266 like WiFi modules

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to make a circuit using [Nodemcu ESP8266](http://www.nodemcu.com/index_en.html) to control the speed and direction of 3 DC servo motors, however I am short of analog pins.
So are there any ways to increase the number of analog pins?
Or are there other WiFi modules like the ESP8266, but with more number of analog pins?

Comment: Short of Analog input pins or output pins? ESP8266 can do PWM on all it's output pins.

Comment: I need to control both speed and direction of multiple motors via WiFi, can PWM signals do that?

Comment: Your question noted that you don't have enough Analog pins -- what do you need them for? **HOW** are you controlling motors? There are many different ways, modules, and methods. Please add detail to your question.

Comment: ESP32 has much more pins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many PWMs do you need?

[Here](https://www.electronicwings.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-pwm-with-arduino-ide) you can find a useful description about PWMs on ESP8266 NodeMCU.

According to image, ESP8266 NodeMcu has 9 PWMs pin.

[image: ESP8266 PWM Pinout]